# Netbeans fails to build signed Jar

Tags: java, netbeans-7.1

I get no error when I just clean and build and I can run the *.java file without no problem. But when I click on run project (the button with green triangle). I get this error message below after building project.

```
init:
Deleting: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Copy libraries to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib.
Building jar: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/Home_Security_Survelliance_Server.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
javaws "/home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/launch.jnlp"
jnlp:
sign-jars:
Signing JAR: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/Home_Security_Survelliance_Server.jar to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/Home_Security_Survelliance_Server.jar as selfsigned
Signing JAR: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacpp.jar to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacpp.jar as selfsigned
Signing JAR: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacv-linux-x86_64.jar to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacv-linux-x86_64.jar as selfsigned
Signing JAR: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacv.jar to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/lib/javacv.jar as selfsigned
generate-jnlp:
Copying 1 file to /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist
Deleting: /home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/dist/launch.jnlp_
generate-html-preview:
jar:
jws-run:
/home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server/nbproject/jnlp-impl.xml:355: Execute failed: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws" (in directory "/home/danny/NetBeansProjects/Home Security Survelliance Server"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor125.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 22 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I sign the jar incorrectly?

Comment: My first guess would be spaces-in-directory-name: "Home Security Survelliance Server"

Comment: Didn't think about it like that. But I was able to build it before I signed the application. Plus Netbeans should give a warning about using spaces in project names. Hmmm.

Comment: @paulsm4 I removed spaces and still gives the exact error and stacktrace. I used '-' is that a valid path character in linux?

Answer (score 0):

I know this stupid to answer my own question. But I solved it by unchecking web start. I thought I needed to check web start to sign my jar. But it signs without it.